# tiling a multi-dimensional numpy array into a lower dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `(100,128,128)` shaped array and want to convert it into a `(1280,1280)` array. Actually `(128,128)` is the size of the images and there are 100 of them. I want to tile all images on a single grid like

`im1  im2  im3  ... im10`

`im11 im12 im13 ... im20`

and so on.

Comment: reshape to (10,10,128,128).  Transpose some axes, and reshape to the target shape.

Comment: `images.reshape(10,10,128,128).swapaxes(2,1).reshape(1280,1280)` works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming arr is your array:

```
arr=np.broadcast_to(arr,(128,128,100))
arr.reshape(1280,1280)
```